# Spectral projection onto singleton

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-graph-theory

Let $H$ be a bounded linear operator on some separable Hilbert space such that $H$ has pure point spectrum on the interval $[a,b]$: $\sigma_{pp}(H)=[a,b]$. Note that here we define the pure point part of the spectrum as the closure of the set of eigenvalues. That means that a given point $x\in[a,b]$ may be either an eigenvalue or one could find an eigenvalue arbitrarily close to it.

So let $x\in[a,b]$ *not* be an eigenvalue of $H$. Is $\chi_{\{x\}}(H)=0$? If not, what does it project onto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be zero.

Note that for something like $\chi_{\{x\}}(H)$ to make sense, you need $H$ to be selfadjoint, or at least normal.

Since $t\,\chi_{\{x\}}(t)=x\,\chi_{\{x\}}(t)$, we have $H\chi_{\{x\}}(H)=x\,\chi_{\{x\}}(H)$. So if $\chi_{\{x\}}(H)y=y$ with $y\ne0$, we  have
$$
Hy=H\chi_{\{x\}}(H)y=x\,\chi_{\{x\}}(H)y=x\,y, 
$$
and $x$ is an eigenvalue.